# Accessing post values by input name in php

Tags: php, forms

I have the following code-

```
     <?php
                $input = array();
                for($i=0; $i<15; $i++)
                $input[]=$i;
                shuffle($input);

                $file="data.xml";
                $test= new SimpleXMLElement($file, null, true); ?>
                 <?php      

                          for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
                  ?> 

                <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="form">
                     <p id="ques"><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->ques?> </p>
                     <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="0" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[0]; ?></p>
                     <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="1" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[1]; ?></p>
                     <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="2" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[2]; ?></p>
                     <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="3" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[3]; ?></p>   
                 </form>
      <?php } ?>
```

Now, in the submit page how do I use the input name `$input[i]` ?
$_POST[what do I write here?] ?

Comment: FYI: `$input = range(0,15);` replaces your array initialization

Comment: Please try `var_dump($_POST)` and see what the array contains. Learn to help yourself with a little basic debugging rather than asking such trivial questions.

Comment: var_dump is your friend! On the submit page, try var_dump($_POST) to see what the available POST variables are.

Comment: You should include `{}` for your first for loop block, as your code above is ambiguous. Also, have a read of [PHP alternative control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), that should help you in the future with mixed PHP/HTML for loop syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialized `$input` to contain `0..15` in a random order. Next you chose the first 5 entries via `$i`, so `input[$i]` will have a random number between 0 and 15. If you use this as a `name` attribute, you will not have a constant set of POST parameters to use.

So I suggest you do something like:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="form">
    <p id="ques"><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->ques?> </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="question" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="0" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[0]; ?></p>
    ....
    <p id="option"><input type="radio" name="q<?php echo $input[$i]?>" value="3" /><?php echo $test->easy->question[$input[$i]]->option[3]; ?></p>   
</form>
```

In the submit page read `$_POST['question']`, this gives you back your `$i`, then read `$_POST["q$i"]`

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. but I set the value to be `<?php echo $input[$i] ?>` instead of `<?php echo $i ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off, you've got a problem because you're going to have 5 different `form`s on the page, and I'm guessing you only want one. So you need the `form` tag outside the `for` loop.

When the form is submitted, you need to check for each parameter. These will be `$_POST[0]`, `$_POST[1]`, through `$_POST[14]` - you will need to see which ones exist.

However, I would not name input variables only with numbers. Rather make each `radio` have a

```
<input type="radio" name = "i<?php echo $input[$i]; ?>" ...
```

Then you are looking for `$_POST["i0"]` through `$_POST["i14"]`. Use `array_key_exists("i0", $_POST)` to determine if it exists (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php).